PHP: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' and Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver
OS: Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon
PHP Version: 8.3

I'm learning PHP and have installed it using the PPA ppa:ondrej/php. I’m trying to connect to a MySQL database that’s running inside a Docker container.
The Docker file:
FROM mysql

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
ENV MYSQL_USER=user
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=blog

COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

EXPOSE 3306

The container is up and running as I am able to connect with it using python as well run SQL queries by going into the docker container.
When I run the PHP built in server using php -S localhost:8080, I get the following error log
[Thu Sep 26 11:14:47 2024] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20230831/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20230831/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20230831/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20230831/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Sep 26 11:14:47 2024] PHP 8.3.11 Development Server (http://localhost:8080) started
[Thu Sep 26 11:14:52 2024] 127.0.0.1:38112 Accepted
[Thu Sep 26 11:14:52 2024] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in /home/anon/Desktop/php/index.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 /home/anon/Desktop/php/index.php(5): PDO->__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/anon/Desktop/php/index.php on line 5
[Thu Sep 26 11:14:52 2024] 127.0.0.1:38112 [500]: GET / - Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in /home/anon/Desktop/php/index.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 /home/anon/Desktop/php/index.php(5): PDO->__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/anon/Desktop/php/index.php on line 5
[Thu Sep 26 11:14:52 2024] 127.0.0.1:38112 Closing

the index.php:
<?php
    require("utils/functions.php");
    // require("router.php");
    $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=blog;charset=utf8mb4";
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, "user", "pass");
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
    $statement->execute();
    $posts = $statement->fetchAll();
    dd($posts)
?>

the functions.php contains the function dd:
<?php
function dd($supGlo) {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($supGlo);
    echo "</pre>";
    die();
}
?>

I done the following to solve the issue without any success:

Remove php-common and reinstalled PHP
Installed php-mysql
Installed php8.3-mysqlnd
Installed php8.3-pdo-mysql
Installed php8.3-mysql
Uncommented in extension=pdo_mysql in php.ini in both the cli and apache2 directories
restarted the apache2 service
Have confirmed that I only have one PHP version installed
Used phpenmod to enable pdo_mysql and restarted the apache2

When I run php --ri pdo, I get the below output,
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20230831/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20230831/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20230831/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20230831/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql

If I comment the extension=pdo_mysql line in php.ini then the warning, is removed.
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql (tried: /usr/lib/php/20230831/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20230831/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20230831/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20230831/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0'

But the PDO drivers are still missing. Also I have confirmed that the /usr/lib/php/20230831/ directory exists and the shared object pdo_mysql.so also exists in it.

If you installed mysqlnd as an extension, you should also enable it.

When I try to install php8.3-mysqlnd, I get the following Note, selecting 'php8.3-mysql' instead of 'php8.3-mysqlnd'. Also, I have the mysqlnd set as active in my php.ini

Have you activated the PDO extension (pdo.so)?

I have no such extension in my php.ini, checked in both cli and apache2 directory

I solved the above issue,

Firstly, make sure that you have only one version of PHP installed and that you have installed the php-mysql extension from your package manager.
Then inside your /etc/php/cli and /etc/php/apache2 directories, edit your php.ini, search for the extension_dir and set it to your extension directory.
To find your extension directory, go to /lib/php/******* the ******** represents YYYYMMDD and can be different for you but will always be in that format, i.e., mine was /lib/php/20230831. This is your extension directory
Also, if you're using a docker container, make sure that your PDO host is 127.0.0.1 and not localhost

